# Command rpmbuild modifies the binary

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

The **rpmbuild** tool is used to generate the rpm file using command

```
rpmbuild -bb sample.spec
```

The **sha1sum** of one of the binary inside the **sample.spec** is computed before rpmbuild.

After the **sample.rpm** is build, it is extracted using the command
    rpm2cpio sample.rpm | cpio -idvm

The binary in the extracted directory has a different sha1sum for the binary for which the sha1sum was computed earlier.

Is this expected? How to avoid this change made to the binary?

Comment: Try manually running `strip` on the binary and then compare. The `rpmbuild` process will strip out any extras (like debug info for a separate RPM).

Answer (score 0):

try this in the spec file

```
%define __os_install_post %{nil}
```